# How to wrap the word in XSL-FO Inside a table?

Tags: xsl-fo

In XSL-FO I have some issues in wrap the word. I want a **word break at the end of the line** and all the text are must be in **justify** inside a table cell. Please help me for the same? For ex:

The  provisions  of   this   endorsement  **be-**
**come**  applicable  commencing on   the  date
occurs. But if your policy (meaning the **pol-**
**icy**  period  in which  this endorsement  ap-

In this content the word **be- is in the first line come is wrapped to the next line**. I also need all the text in this content are in justified manner, this content is present inside one column in the able. Likewise I need some word is wrapped in this. Help me for this same in XSLFO CODING.

Comment: Please share the source xml fragment for that table-cell and show the expected end result.

Answer (score 0):

Inhibiting the word break can be specified by "hyphenate" property.

7.10.4 "hyphenate"

https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#hyphenate

Also justification can be specified by "text-align" property.

7.16.9 "text-align"

https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#text-align

As the both properties are inheritable, you can specify them at fo:table (or fo:table-body if you want apply different formatting for fo:table-header)

```
<fo:table hyphenate="false" text-align="justify">
```

Here is sample formatting result using Antenna House XSL Formatter.

[image: Formatting result]

The relevant XSL-FO:

```
<fo:table-and-caption text-align="center">
  <fo:table border="thin solid black" hyphenate="false" text-align="justify" width="50%">
    <fo:table-body>
      <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell>
          <fo:block>
           The provisions of this endorsement become applicable commencing on the date
           occurs. But if your policy (meaning the policy period in which this endorsement ...)
          </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-body>
  </fo:table>
</fo:table-and-caption>
```

Comment: Thanks. I want the word become like **be-** with hyphenate symbol in first line and **come** is wrapped to next line. And all the text are align in justify. If word spacing is different, no worries.

Comment: Sorry, but I also read your example as saying that you did not want 'become' to be hyphenated. If you want to enable hyphenation, change `hyphenate="false"` to `hyphenate="true"`.